# Got an error when I compile project with OpenNetCF

Tags: c#, forms, windows-mobile, controls, opennetcf

I need to work on old project that use OpenNetCF round buttons

I reference all the OpenNetCF dll to the project.

I have 2 problems:

1. I can't see the round button on the forms
2. when I compiled I see this error:

> Could not find type
>   'MyControl.Controls.RoundPictureButton'.
>   Please make sure that the assembly
>   that contains this type is referenced.
>   If this type is a part of your
>   development project, make sure that
>   the project has been successfully
>   built.

Comment: Maybe you should paste some code right buddy?

Answer (score 1):

The error says '**MyControl.Controls**.RoundPictureButton'  Note the bolded portion there.  The namespace is not from OpenNETCF (OpenNETCF doesn't have a RoundPictureButton that I recall), it's a control from some other assembly or location and the compiler is unable to locate it.  You need to either add a reference to the assembly that contains that control or you need to add the source file that defines it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something changed on your solution configuration, so it's possible that you have missed some project to be added on the solution, or just have been moved some day and deleted from the solution by mistake.

See you.